# React native Animated API not working with recompose

Tags: reactjs, react-native, higher-order-components, recompose

I have a HOC made in recompose that isn't behaving properly - it just shows the component at it's end value without ever animating. The same component, written as a regular class, behaves fine. Can someone tell me what is causing this issue, or how I would approach this so it works correctly?

recompose HOC component:

```
const enhancer = compose(
  withState('slideAnim', 'setSlide', new Animated.Value(width)),
  withState('fadeAnim', 'setFadeAnim', new Animated.Value(0)),
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount () {
      Animated.parallel([
        Animated.timing(this.props.slideAnim, {
          toValue: 0,
          duration: 500
        }),
        Animated.timing(this.props.fadeAnim, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 500
        })
      ]).start()
    }
  })
)

const ModalScene = ({ children, slideAnim, fadeAnim }) => {
  return (
    <Animated.View style={[styles, { opacity: fadeAnim, left: slideAnim }]}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  )
}
```

regular class:

```
class ModalScene extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      slideAnim: new Animated.Value(width),
      fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    Animated.parallel([
      Animated.timing(this.state.slideAnim, {
        toValue: 0,
        duration: 500
      }),
      Animated.timing(this.state.fadeAnim, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 500
      })
    ]).start()
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Animated.View
        style={[
          styles,
          { opacity: this.state.fadeAnim, left: this.state.slideAnim }
        ]}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just forget to export HOC, try this: 
`export default enhancer(ModalScene);`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which seemed to be caused by the mutable nature of the Animated objects. To make sure an instance of `Animated.Value` was created for each instance of my components I had to use the other form of `withState`, the one that takes a function as initial value. Try changing these lines:

```
withState('slideAnim', 'setSlide', new Animated.Value(width)),
withState('fadeAnim', 'setFadeAnim', new Animated.Value(0)),
```

to

```
withState('slideAnim', 'setSlide', () => new Animated.Value(width)),
withState('fadeAnim', 'setFadeAnim', () => new Animated.Value(0)),
```